# Custom color map in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, customization, colormap

I'm trying to create a colormap to use with matplotlib for value ranges with different sizes. For example, the first range is from 0 to 0.7, the second from 0.7 to 0.9 e the last to 0.9 to 1. I have specific colors for each of the points (0, 0.7, 0.9 and 1.0). Between the points the colormap should be interpolated the values.

In sum, the points are like this:

- Point 0: black (RGB: 0,0,0);
- Point 0.7: red (RGB: 255,0,0);
- Point 0.9: yellow (RGB: 255,255,0);
- Point 1: green (RGB: 0,255,0).

I've looked at matplotlib documentation but I didn't find a way to set specific custom points. I've searched here too, but I couldn't a question with this specific problem.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.